# Take question mark off end of string in PHP

Tags: php, string, variables, web

I'm new to php, but wasn't able to find a straight answer online, so decided to ask Stack Overflow.

I have a variable, and I want to make a statement similar to the following:

```
if ($var has a question mark at end)
{
$var = ($var - question mark)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

--EDIT--

I ended up using the following:

```
if (substr($var, -1) == "?")
{
$var = rtrim($input, "?");
}
```

Thanks again for the quick feedback. God I love this site.

--END EDIT--

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/strpos http://php.net/substr

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/rtrim

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer you chose as the correct one, it's our way to say "thank you" for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
$var = rtrim($var, '?');
```

Answer (score 2):

**hakre** is right

`$var = rtrim($var, '?');`

Answer (score 0):

What about using [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.strpos.php) function?

**example**

```
$mystring = 'abc?';
$findme   = '?';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if($pos === true)
{
      //we've found it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = (substr($var,-1) == "?") ? substr($var,0,-1) : $var;
```

Explanation:

`substr($var, -1)` gets the last character in your string

then it compares whether that string has question mark or not at the end.

If it has a question mark at the end, it removes it, if it doesn't it leaves the string as is.

The code above is a shorthand version of `if(){....} else {}` The instructions after the unquoted question mark represent the true block, the instructions after the colon `:` represent the false block.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
if ($var[strlen($var) - 1] == "?")
{
    $var = substr($var, 0, strlen($var) - 1);
}
```